# What's the default filesystem installed on vmware vCenter?

Tags: vmware, vcenter

I googled around and details like this aren't usually in the marketing info.

I know vCenter is based on SLE 11 and btrfs is an option for installable filesystems, but I don't know how vCenter is actually set up because I don't have access to an installation.

Can somebody who has vCenter installed do a df -T and post the results?

I just need to know if there's any non-ext filesystems in a default vCenter install.

Thanks.

Comment: What VMWare product are you talking about specifically?  I am only familar with, VMWare vCenter <Server>, but your question with related to what I am familar with does not make sense.  Please don't reply to this comment, just clarify your quesiton, by editing your question.

Comment: vCenter is an application for controlling ESXI hosts which can be installed on windows, linux, etc, so it doesn't implement filesystems at all. do yo mean ESXI?  Anyway, the version of `df` that ships with ESXI does not support -T.

Comment: @FrankThomas - Exactly.  vCenter is the server application installed on an OS.  VCenter communicates with ESXi hosts.  vSphere communciates with ESXi/vCenter to manage the VMs.  The question is flat out confusing.

Comment: My misunderstanding then. As it was presented to me, I thought vcenter was an entire solution provided with a box and everything, I did not realize it was an application you added to whatever setup you had. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESXI uses VMWare's VMFS filesystem both for system partitions for the host, and Datastore volumes. Check the link below to determine what version of VMFS is used by your version of ESXI.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_VMFS

Comment: gotchya, I see I had the wrong picture to start with, thanks for the info.